# Is Perl used for web development?

Tags: php, web-development, perl

I am a web developer. I have been using php for many years and I also know lots of other programming languages so I wanted to try making websites using them.

I know Perl and want to make a website using one of its frameworks (probably Dancer) but I've heard people saying that Perl isn't used for web development anymore and that there is no point in using it for a website. I have also been told that Perl has been replaced by php. Is Perl still used for server-side web development or has it been replaced by php?

Comment: "I've heard people saying that Perl isn't used for web development anymore" When you hear such bold claims, _always_ ask for backing evidence. More often than not you'll find out that the claim is pure nonsense.

Comment: Anyone who tells you Perl is not used for web development clearly knows nothing about web development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some people still use it (I'm one of them). So, it hasn't been replaced. In fact, I switched to Perl from PHP.

Comment: Do you use perl itself or a framework? If you use a framework which one because I'm still not sure which framework is the best.

Comment: @one2three: I prefer Dancer, at least for smaller projects.

Comment: Awesome thanx. I was going to use Dancer but was a bit unsure about it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is. DuckDuckGo is one company that I know of that started with Perl as the server side language. I believe they are still using Perl primarily.

1. https://github.com/duckduckgo

Answer (score 0):

PHP, in my opinion, is a much faster and better choice for the web. We also have Javascript, which is blazing fast due to it's event-based nature. However Perl is still used and there are web frameworks for Perl in web use such as [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/).

There is also an emergence of Python being used in the web. Frameworks such as [Django](http://djangoproject.com), which I have had personal experience with and I find it much faster than using Perl in the web. I should also mention Flask, which is a micro web framework designed for use with Python. This can also be an option.

It's really up to yourself what framework/language you use. Personal preference. In the end, if you're comfortable with Perl, use Perl. If you're confident in Javascript or PHP, use that. If you prefer Python overall, use Django.

Hope this helps!

Comment: "_PHP, in my opinion, is a much faster_" **[citation needed]**